# Is there a way of saving a matplotlib chart as a file in tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, savefiledialog

I'm trying to save my graph  but when I choose the file in the directory it says the filename is not defined

```
def save(): 

filename = asksaveasfile(initialfile = 'Untitled.png',defaultextension=".png",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Portable Graphics Format","*.png")])
plt.savefig(flename)
```

Comment: Do you have `from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile` at the start of your code? Also are you aware that there is a difference between `asksaveasfile` and `asksaveasfilename`?

Comment: Yes I did import and no I had no clue ill take a look at it right now thank you

Comment: I looked at it and yes thats exatcly what i want a variable with that name so then i can save the graph with "pls.savefig(filename)", but when i made that change i had the same result: filename is not defined

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but you used `flename` inside the `plt.savefig` instead of `filename`. Is that just from the question or can that be the problem?

Comment: Yes it was from the question I got it to work thank you for trying

Comment: @DavidFrydman I have wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415923/is-there-a-way-of-saving-a-matplotlib-chart-as-a-file-in-tkinter/68416986#68416986), mark that as accepted answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typo errors. Here's you can fix this by doing this:

```
def save():
    filename = asksaveasfilename(initialfile = 'Untitled.png',defaultextension=".png",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Portable Graphics Format","*.png")])
    plt.savefig(filename)
```

At first there is indentation error in your `save` function. You wrote [`asksaveasfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile) which should be corrected as [`asksaveasfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) because we are just asking user to write the file name, not saving file there. And At last you wrote `flename` which is not defined anywhere else in program but I think you are trying to write `filename` cuz we get the filename from user in `filename` in previous line.